Passing URL parameters forward in ASP.NET MVC site
We have a mobile app that directs the user to our web app for some functionality. For example, when a user is registering for membership the are directed out of the Android app to the website registration screen with utm_source=app parameter. However as the user moves throughout the web app experience the utm parameter is lost. We are trying to update the routing on the site to continue passing the parameters forward throughout the journey so we can tell which users converted from the mobile app vs the website.
Is there a way to do this with ASP.NET MVC routing? Or using controller attributes?
We tried using js to capture the onclick event and append any utm params however when there are server side redirects the params are lost
